# Ruby on Rails 4 javascript not executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a custom `js` file in `app/assets/javascripts`.
This is the js file:

```
//app/assets/javascripts/contacts.js
//$(document).ready(function() { //I've already tried with this method

$(window).load(function() {
    alert("foo bar")
});
```

I require the file `contacts.js` file in the `application.js` file.

If I inspect the html page I see the js file loaded correctly, but the message is not shown.
If I reload the page (by pressing f5), the message is correctly show.

When the page is loaded the javascript is loaded (I can see it in source html code in the browser) but not executed.

Can you help me?

***SOLUTION:***
[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Yes, I'm using `turbo-links`

Comment: read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Ok. Your link works for me. solved.

Comment: In rails 5, you can simply say `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { } # Not working with turbo-links
```

[From](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks)

> Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process, the event that
>   this relies on will not be fired. If you have code that looks like
>   this, you must change your code to do this instead:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  // you code here
});
```

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Answer (score 0):

With Turbolinks version 5 (starting from Rails 5) you need to use:

```js
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  // YOUR CODE
});
```