# Coffeescript not executing on Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am trying to do some form validation in my Ruby on Rails app using Coffeescript. However the script isnt executing. I am trying to add a validation to check if password entered and confirmation password entered are equal.

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  password = document.getElementById('user_password').value
  password_confirmation = document.getElementById('user_password_confirmation').value

  validatePassword = ->
    password = document.getElementById('user_password').value
    password_confirmation = document.getElementById('user_password_confirmation').value
    if password.value != password_confirmation.value
      password_confirmation.setCustomValidity 'Passwords Don\'t Match'
    else
      password_confirmation.setCustomValidity ''
    return

  password.onchange = validatePassword
  password_confirmation.onkeyup = validatePassword
```

I added `$(document).on 'ready page:load'` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811654/ruby-on-rails-4-javascript-not-executed) but it does not seem to have any effect.

My corresponding .html.erb file contains the following code:

```
<%= f.password_field :password,:onkeyup => 'validatePassword()', class: 'form-control',:required=>true %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :onkeyup => 'validatePassword()', class: 'form-control',:required=>true %>
```

Comment: Are you sure this coffescript files in included in your assets pipeline? is it included in the page source? and do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @bigsolom yes it's in my asset folder. The JavaScript file is present once the page loads as well. No error on console

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the script is not run? Did you put `console.log` in your `$(document).on 'ready page:load'` callback and check it?

next thing... I believe it won't work even if script is executed. When defining `validatePassword` function within `page:load` callback you don't assign it to window object. What happens here is just a creation of local function within callback that is unreachable from outside (`validatePassword()` in your `erb` file). you should write `window.validatePassword = ...definition...`

one more thing. This line `password = document.getElementById('user_password').value` returns a value, which is String.  A few lines later you're writing `password.onchange = validatePassword`, but problem is `password` doesn't have onchange property (because it's a String). What you probably wanted to achieve here is `password = document.getElementById('user_password')`

Comment: I corrected the value part in getElementById. I checked chrome debugger and it is following the expected path. However the message set in setCustomvalidity is not executing..I think it is related to the window you mentioned. However I am not able to follow it